# Flow: with existential type deprecated, how to type a React element?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

**Background:** in v.0.72.0, Flow [deprecated](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/Changelog.md#0720) the `*` type (or, as they call it [in the docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-existential-type), the existential type).

**Problem:** How do we now describe the type of a React Element (any element; it could be an element rendered out by a React Component, or by a stateless component (simple function), or whatever is rendered when we write html tags in JSX)?

**Examples in Try Flow:**

[Example 1](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecDCE4EAdkiVnDAJ5hJwByEAJvQL5wBmURcA5FFQY+AKBE06cACpIAzjAAKPMLLgBeXCLhw0RSGQoAuRiyQi2YzgFcSGYKWlyYACjy7iB+G2Mz5SiCoAlJragjBWUCRwzlpwAJAAPMzAAG4AfDju+uQwbAkA9MnpsYEA3OaWNnYOAGIQEM5gyrLGOGzBOCJxYRFRCWBpABJIADYjEHAA7tAjzACEBQMVIrok8nAAHupwCb7wWaQ5ajgJdRD5aRwXK6Tr1Nu7Tjp6hxTHCShpABaj41MzzAKnzYFyAA) — typing as `Node`. This works, but Node is too broad a type, which, besides React elements, includes also strings, numbers, booleans, etc. I would like to narrow the type down.

[Example 2](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecDCE4EAdkiVnDAJ5hJwCiANkiOfAL5wBmURcAciioMAgFBiadOABUkAZxgAFPmHlwAvLjFw4aIpDIUAXIxZsKAHgBUAPjEcJ3AK4kMwUrIUwAFHn3ERpymcooqEGoAlNq6wjDOUCRwPjpwAJCWACbAAG62OAGG7ByWAPTZeamRANwOTq7ungBiEBA+YKrypjgc0ThiaXEJSZZgtgASSExMEHAA7tBMmQCEZWN1YvokinAAHppwlqHwhaTsGjiWLRCltly3m6Q71AdH3noGZxQXlii2ABZTGbzRaZMp-Di3IA) — typing as `Element<*>`. This also works, but as pointed out above, the `*` type is now on its way out.

[Example 3](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecDCE4EAdkiVnDAJ5hJwCiANkiOfAL5wBmURcAciioMAgFBiadOABUkAZxgAFPmHlwAvLjFw4aIpDIUAXIxZsKAHilII3AgdLsAfGI4TuAVxIZgpWQowABR4+sRGnKZyiioQagCU2rrCMJ5QJHBBOnAAkJYAJsAAbs44YYbsHJYA9IUl2fEA3G4e3r7+AGIQEEFgqvKmOByJOGI5KWkZlmDOABJITEwQcADu0Ez5AIQ1My1i+iSKcAAemnCW0fDlThQaOJZdENXOXM-7pEfUZxeBeo4Rd0sKGcAAsFktVut8jVgRxnkA) — typing as `Element<typeof Component>`, as per [documentation](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/#toc-react-element). This doesn’t work. Is there a proper way to make it work?

Comment: Your usage of `Element<typeof Component>` is wrong. It's supposed to work with a "real" component from your code, for example, you can write `Element<typeof Foo>` if `Foo` extends Component or if `Foo` is a stateless functional component.

Comment: Yep, I figured it was wrong because all examples in the docs used specific components, but I couldn’t figure how to make it general enough so that it would work with any component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you [can](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecYCeYScAwhOBAHZJUwAqRS2hxcAogDZIi3wC+cAGZQKcAORRUGcQChZrEvSQBnGAAVRYFQB5y4AHxwAvLllw4aCpBp0AXB2686e6wdn95QgK5UMwajhlNVdwTQhtbH0wB2jqPkZiULBw7SMAHzg1KGAqAHMDAAo8K0pbAQdgjS1daIMASjMLKRhvKCo4QvM4AEgdABNgADcDHFKbPn4dAHpBke76gG4PL19-QIAxCAhCsBqHHH5GnFkelraOnTADAAkkTk4IOAB3aE5+gEIZ65XZKyo1HAAB4mOA6KqWazxOjGHA6LYQaYGQRIv7UQEEUHg1TwcbQmCwnQoAwAC3ujxeb36M2J-FR-0BAC8sRC8eVYeJsrk8uI6QYgA) use generics

Comment: Very cool! But I realized my example in try Flow is a little bit different from my actual code, which uses class components instead of functional components, and I am not entirely sure how to translate your example into a class component. Do you think this would be ok (it doesn't even use generics):

Comment: https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecDCE4EAdkiVnDAJ5hIFGRkUAqtS2NdcAogDZIQ5eAF84AMyhE4AciioMMgFBKu9FkgDOMAApSwmuAF5cSuHDSNSwgFy8BQigB5CxZjDZ0nOEQD44AD5w2lDAJADmvkoiKmh8KJqGGtr48YlwSAAeMOQAJoauTMJOybr6mv44KubyJLlIUAAUAJSm5gCQliTauBZW7nBiJjAAFsCaAHRg5QDcSu3yMACuUCRwTrnAAG6+OJZuwiJOAPSbO2aDKjFK4kskGMCkcABiEBCN0xAGdj6tVQtIZardZgXwACSQfD4EDgAHdoHxcgBCE6g6KxUg9TLGdalVIJQz7IoUIw4JyvCDHXxiKlKLo9ag4kpaGD49JE6wkskoXwjSHQuEI3InHkiWn0+AALyZeLShP6wlJMhCYXCMjFviAA

Comment: Your example will not work in [some cases](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecDCE4EAdkiVnDAJ5hIFGRkUAqtS2NdcAogDZIQ5eAF84AMyhE4AciioMMgFBKu9FkgDOMAApSwmuAF5cSuHDSNSwgFy8BQigB5CxZjDZ0nOEQD44AD5w2lDAJADmvkoiKmh8KJqGGtr48YlwSAAeMOQAJoauTMJOybr6mv44KubyJLlIUAAUAJSm5gCQliTauBZW7nBiJjAAFsCaAHRg5QDcSu3yMACuUCRwTrnAAG6+OJZuwiJOAPSbO2aDKjFK4kskGMCkcABiEBCN0xAGdngodiFhcKDVpVBZIZardZgXwACSQfD4EDgAHdoHxcgBCE7Q6KxUg9TLGdalVIJQz7IoUIw4JyvCDHXxiBlAA)

Comment: I feared it will turn out this way :-( Could you please suggest an improvement?

Comment: Yes, sorry for giving [this link](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecDCE4EAdkiVnDAJ5hIFGRkUAqtS2NdcAogDZIQ5eAF84AMyhE4AciioMMgFBKu9FkgDOMAApSwmgDw6AfHAC8uJXDhpGpYQC5eAoRUOFizGGzrGzAD5w2lDAJADmJkoiKmh8KJqacBra+PGJ-nBIAB4w5AAmSZ5MwoYpuvpGpmY4KjbyJPlIUAAUAJRWNgCQdiTauLb23nBiljAAFsCaAHRglQDcSl3yMACuUCRwhvnAAG4mOHZewiKGAPQ7+9YjKjFK4qskGMCkcABiEBAtcxAGzngoZwhMLhEYdWrLJBrDZbMAmAASSD4fAgcAA7tA+PkAITnOHRWKkfrZCxbcppBJJI4lCjmHCGD6olDmABELLOJjEHKAA) in a separate comment